# Replace "search with google" with "search with bing" in context menu

Tags: shortcut-menu, search-engine

Is there a way to replace this context menu item to search with Bing instead of Google? I looked under `Keyboard shortcuts > Services` but can't find how to change/add this option.

Comment: Good! Nobody likes Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change it in safari :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And is there a way to open that link in Google Chrome instead of Safari?

Comment: If chrome is your default browser perhaps.

Comment: It is...but no go....